# How do I properly handle the href value on a link when making ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, ajax, onclick, href

To quickly explain, all of the links on my page currently use the following format:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="loadPageWithAjax();">Link</a>
```

What I'd like to do is upgrade the code to something like the following:

```
<a href="actual/path/to/content" onclick="loadPageWithAjax();">Link</a>
```

My goal is two-fold:

1. Make the status bar show the URL that the link leads to
2. Allow users to copy the link location and have it be a valid URL

My problem is that this then ignores the onclick and actually redirects to the URL. Whats the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, then I suggest using [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) or [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/). They both provide good support for HTML5 pushState with a fallback for HTML4 browsers. Using pushState, you'll be able to update the URL (to make it bookmarkable) and you can use the statechange event to handle navigation (like when the user hits the back button). Take a look at the documentation for History.js to see some examples of how it works.

Update:

Per your comment, I suggest creating an event handler for links that you want handled via an AJAX request.

For example, lets say all links you want to be ajaxy have the "ajaxify" class.

```
$(document).on("click", "a.ajaxify", function(e) {
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    History.pushState({}, null, url);

    // do something, like make an ajax request to get the url

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: So I'm actually already using History.js. Here is an actual example of a link I'm talking about:

`<a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:History.pushState(null, null, '/user/<?=$username?>');"><?=$username?></a>`

Comment: I added an example to my answer that might help you. Rather than using onclick, it creates an event listener to handle the onclick event. The key here is using e.preventDefault() to stop the browser from trying to loading the URL like it normally does, which sounds like the problem you are currently having.

Comment: Ah duh. Thats pretty simple and much cleaner than the way I was currently implementing it. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

In your `loadPageWithAjax()` function, you need to be able to take the event data that it is automatically called by the browser.

```
function loadPageWithAjax(e){
    e.preventDefault(); stops page from clicking
    //do your ajax stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the URL of the address bar without changing loading the page unless you use hashes using window.location.hash, or the new `history.pushState`, which is only available to HTML5 browsers.

Comment: I'm actually already using History API (via History.js). However that only replaces the URL after the link is clicked. You can't right click > copy hyperlink on the url cause the value is ";" from the href